# How can I change the values on the x-axis of my bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe which produces the following plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,3,5]})
df['column_name'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I change the x-axis values from 4, 2, 3, 5 to Gen Y, Gen X, Gen Z, and Greatest, respectively. Here is my desired output:

[image]

Comment: freq = df['column_name'].value_counts() 
freq.index = ['Gen Y', 'Gen X', 'Gen Z', 'Greatest'] 
freq.plot(kind='bar')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plt.xticks() to replace the x value for each column like below:

```
df['column_name'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3],['Gen Y', 'Gen X', 'Gen Z', 'Greatest'])
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, when I tried your solution, I got the following error:

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xticks'

Comment: @deb It looks like you tried to use it with ax.xticks in a subplot setting.  plt does have an xticks attribute whereas ax does not.  Instead it has a set_xticks() method.  If you copy and paste the above code exactly, you won't see any errors.